# How to animate a curve graph?

Tags: animation, modifiers

how can we animate a falloff graph (called map curve in bpy) , similar to the one in the vertex-group edit modifier?

Blender don't let me add any keyframe.. it seem to be impossible, please prove me wrong.

[image]